# I want to run query and find all my pending notifications.

Tags: discussion

I was playing around the query builder: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

I wanted to check whether its possible to query and get the pending notifications(includes inbox, post edited, votes notifications) for a given user?

Is it possible?

Comment: Not by SEDE. The API supports it though: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread

Comment: Hmmm, thats sad. But a quick question, if the schema shared via SEDE is exactly the same used in production, then can't we build our own `inbox-unread` api?

Comment: Because it's not the same as in production. It doesn't contain personal user data (notifications/post votes etc...)

Comment: You can find the SEDE tables and their purpose in the [Database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) answer over on MSE.